# Get created type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 database.

I want to get the created types stored in the database.

**Example**:

If I create the types:

```
create type t1 as
(
  cola varchar,
  colb varchar
);
```

How can I get the details of them in pgAdmin III?

Comment: You need to enable the display for the "Browser Tool": http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/options-browser.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Yeah! Got it. But is there any script to details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pg_type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-type.html) system catalog:

```
SELECT * FROM PG_TYPE WHERE typname='t1';
```